# Cannot get the parameters in the server

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I got a problem when I try to get parameters from the request, I got nothing but NULL. 
The JSP file is like this:

```
    <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>

<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html"  prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean"  prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic" prefix="logic" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html:html locale="true">
    <head>
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="cache-control" CONTENT="no-cache">
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="expires" CONTENT="0">
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Style-Type"  content="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/base.css">

        <title>Menu</title>
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
<!--
    function nextPage(url) {
        location.replace(url);
    }
    function setUrl(url) {
        document.forms[0].url.value = url;
    }
//-->
</SCRIPT>

    </head>
    <body tabindex="-1">
        <%-- ページ・ボディ --%>
        <html:form action="/select.do?apl500_p=1" method="post" target="_self" >
            <html:hidden property="url" value ="" />

            <table style="width:100%;" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:100%;text-align:center">
                        <font size="5" color="#000000">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <B>Menu</B></font>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align:right">
                        <html:submit property="submit_logout" value="Logout" tabindex="-1"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <hr><br>

            <div align="center" style="width:90%;height:482px;overflow:auto;margin-left:40px;">
            <table  border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:100%;text-align:center">
<html:submit property="btn1" value="アプリケーション１" onclick="setUrl('/aplXXX')" style="width:400px;height=150px;font-size:14pt;"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:100%;text-align:center">
<html:submit property="btn2" value="新共通認証システム（ローカル環境用）テスト" onclick="setUrl('/authTest')" style="width:400px;height=150px;font-size:14pt;"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            </div>

            <%-- ページ・フッダー --%>
            <%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jsp/footer.inc" %>

        </html:form>
    </body>
</html:html>
<% out.flush(); %>
```

When I used "request.getParameterNames()", I can only get the "apl500_p" parameter, I cannot get the "url" parameter. I used the tomcat7.0.41, but if I use the tomcat5.5.36,it's Ok.
I don't know why. Is there something wrong with tomcat7.0.41?
I used Fiddler2 and I'm sure that the "url" parameter was sent to the server.

Comment: how u requesting the params at the request page?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what exactly you mean?I request the params at the action class.

Comment: i mean at the action hope u r using request.getparamter?

Comment: I found the problem, the japanese,If I change the japanese "アプリケーション１" to english, it will work.Maybe the problem is encoding.

Comment: ohhh...for this use `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");` at the strt of ur `doget` or `dopost` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the discussion that you had, I suspect that the parameter `url` is NULL because the character encoding used by the browser is different from the character encoding used by the server.

Before the browser sends a parameter to the server, it URL-encodes the parameter. This encoding method encodes certain characters (e.g, Japanese characters) using percent encoding. Percent encoding method works by first converting the character into bytes, based on the specified character set. After that, it encodes these bytes into a sequence of hexadecimal digits, prefixed by "%" character. This character set is what I mean by character encoding used by the browser.

The server then decodes the retrieved parameter back into its original form. It does this by first decoding the sequence of hexadecimal digits into a sequence bytes. After that, it convert each bytes into a character, based on the specified character set. The problem here is that the server needs to use the same character set as the one used by the browser. It is often that the request does not carry information about the character set used by the browser, causing the server to make a best effort guess. If the guess is incorrect, the decoding process fails silently, and NULL is returned, which is what happened in your case.

Different web servers have different ways to make the guess. Web server may look at the Content-Type header, Content-Language header, Accept header, Accept Language header, configuration file, and so on.

As I am not familiar with both Tomcat versions, I am not able to pin point exactly how to fix the problem. But, you can start by studying how Tomcat figure out the character encoding. In WebSphere Application Server, there is a configuration file that can be modified to specify the default character encoding used by the server.

The parameter `apl500_p` is not NULL because the URL-encoded-form of `1` is also `1`. The server does not have any problem decoding it back.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the apl500_p=1 in the form action value

```
 action="/select.do"
```

This way it will pass all your form elements to the servlet. Adding parameters to the form action prevents this. If you need your apl500_p value, I suggest you make another hidden field like:

```
 <html:hidden property="apl500_p" value ="1" />
```

Comment: I tried, but it still does not work. I can get url from the ServletInputStream:   stream:  url=%2FaplXXX&apl500_p=1&btn1=%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%EF%BC%91.   but I can not get url from parameter or attribute.

Comment: Is setUrl(url) being called when you submit the form using btn1 and btn2?